# Can't transfer to new screen without view controller on iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ios7.1

I have a table view that is dynamically created via JSON and I want it to be so when I click on one of those items in the table view that I get transferred to a new screen. 

I have this working using a project that I found online, but the project is for a older iOS and uses nibs. 
The screen that I want to transfer to also has to be dynamic via the same JSON file. I need to know how to create the dynamic screen to transfer to and how to get the current code to transfer to that screen working.

Here is my current code to transfer to a new screen ( remember it is from a older iOS ) :

```
#pragma mark - Table view delegate
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath    
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    PeopleDetailsViewController *detailViewController = [[PeopleDetailsViewController      alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    detailViewController.details = self.data[indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

EDIT. This is my current code to create the details view.(view that needs to be dynamic):

```
#import "PeopleDetailsViewController.h"

@interface PeopleDetailsViewController ()

@end

@implementation PeopleDetailsViewController
@synthesize details;

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (NSString *)name {
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.details[@"Tag"],     self.details[@"B"]];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

self.title = [self name];
 }

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
 {
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

 #pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
     return 1;
 }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:  (NSInteger)section {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return 2;
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:     (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (!cell)
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        cell.textLabel.text = [self name];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @":Tag";
        break;
    case 1: {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @":Value";
        cell.textLabel.text = self.details[@"Value"];
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Why not simply pass the details via a method which will then create/populate your view based on them?

Comment: Well i would love to do that but i don't know how lol

Comment: Any idea's would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have (mostly) everything you need. Your table view data source is for now hardcoded, so you will have to change this part of your code. The method names are pretty self-explanatory.

What you should do :

- Add a method in `PeopleDetailsViewController` called, for example '`-(void) setDetails : (type)name` which will be used to pass the details to the new controller. At the end of this function you should call `[self.tableView reloadData];` - this will tell your table view that the data has changed and it should reload it (calling the methods under `#pragma mark - Table view data source`)
- Change the above mentiod methods, so that they don't return hardcoded values, but rather ones passed in details.

If you want non-standard table cells, you can design them in Interface Bulder and assign a custom class to them with `IBOutlets` and then populate them with data similarily.